# aggregating data with filters in dashboard in google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, cumulative-line-chart

//Google charts with filtered data

```
     google.charts.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

      function drawDashboard() {

        // Create our data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
      data.addColumn('number', 'coverage');
      data.addColumn('number', 'coverage_change');
      data.addColumn('number', 'depth');
      data.addColumn('number', 'depth_change');
      data.addColumn('number', 'breadth');
      data.addColumn('number', 'breadth_change');
      data.addRows([
        ['Restaurants','Jan',0.177,0,2.489329,0,112.019805,0],
        ['Hotels','Jan',0.3411,0,1.216445,0,52.307135,0],
        ['Movies','Jan',0.4748,0,0.312464,0,9.686384,0],
        ['Attractions','Jan',0,0,0,0,0,0],
        ['Destinations','Jan',0,0,0,0,0,0],
        ['Events','Jan',0,0,0,0,0,0],
        ['All','Jan',0.2092,0,4.018238,0,174.013324,0],
        ['Restaurants','Feb',0.177,0,2.489329,0,112.019805,0],
        ['Hotels','Feb',0.3411,0,1.216445,0,52.307135,0],
        ['Movies','Feb',0.4748,0,0.312464,0,9.686384,0],
        ['Attractions','Feb',0,0,0,0,0,0],
        ['Destinations','Feb',0,0,0,0,0,0],
        ['Events','Feb',0,0,0,0,0,0],
        ['All','Feb',0.2092,0,4.018238,0,174.013324,0]


      ]);



        // Create a dashboard.
        var dashboard = new      google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

        // Create a range slider, passing some options
        var filter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Category'},
            'ui': {
              'allowTyping': false,
              'allowMultiple': false,
              'labelStacking': 'vertical'
            }
        });

        // Create a pie chart, passing some options
        var Chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'LineChart',
          'containerId': 'chart1_div',
          'options': {
            'width': 1000,
            'height': 300},
            'view': {'columns': [1,2]},
            'dataTable' : google.visualization.data.group(data, [0],
                [{'column': 2, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}])
          });


         var Chart2 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'LineChart',
          'containerId': 'chart2_div',
          'options': {
            'width': 1000,
            'height': 300,
            curveType:'function'},
            'view': {'columns': [1,3]} 
        });

        // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
        // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
        // given the chosen slider range.

         dashboard.bind(filter, [Chart2,Chart]);
       // Draw the dashboard.
        dashboard.draw(data);
      }
  </script>
```

//I was able to get two charts with the same filter. But the values are not //aggregated. I used google.visualization.data.group function.. but, it doesn't //seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only one DataTable may be used per Dashboard

so when the Dashboard is drawn, the DataTable on `Chart` is ignored

because it is included in the Dashboard

---

in order to draw a chart using the *aggregated and filtered* data from the Dashboard,

draw the `Chart` independently using the DataTable from `Chart2`,
when the `'ready'` event fires

this event will fire every time `Chart2` is redrawn as a result of the `filter`

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawDashboard,
  packages:['controls']
});

function drawDashboard() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
  data.addColumn('number', 'coverage');
  data.addColumn('number', 'coverage_change');
  data.addColumn('number', 'depth');
  data.addColumn('number', 'depth_change');
  data.addColumn('number', 'breadth');
  data.addColumn('number', 'breadth_change');
  data.addRows([
    ['Restaurants','Jan',0.177,0,2.489329,0,112.019805,0],
    ['Hotels','Jan',0.3411,0,1.216445,0,52.307135,0],
    ['Movies','Jan',0.4748,0,0.312464,0,9.686384,0],
    ['Attractions','Jan',0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ['Destinations','Jan',0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ['Events','Jan',0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ['All','Jan',0.2092,0,4.018238,0,174.013324,0],
    ['Restaurants','Feb',0.177,0,2.489329,0,112.019805,0],
    ['Hotels','Feb',0.3411,0,1.216445,0,52.307135,0],
    ['Movies','Feb',0.4748,0,0.312464,0,9.686384,0],
    ['Attractions','Feb',0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ['Destinations','Feb',0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ['Events','Feb',0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ['All','Feb',0.2092,0,4.018238,0,174.013324,0]
  ]);

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  var filter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'filter_div',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Category'},
      'ui': {
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false,
        'labelStacking': 'vertical'
      }
  });

  var Chart2 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'LineChart',
    'containerId': 'chart2_div',
    'options': {
      'width': 1000,
      'height': 300,
      curveType:'function'},
      'view': {'columns': [1,3]}
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(Chart2, 'ready', function () {
    var Chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'LineChart',
      'containerId': 'chart1_div',
      'options': {
        'width': 1000,
        'height': 300
      },
      'dataTable' : google.visualization.data.group(
        Chart2.getDataTable(),
        [0],
        [{'column': 2, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      )
    });
    Chart.draw();
  });

  dashboard.bind(filter, [Chart2]);
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <div id="filter_div"></div>
  <div id="chart1_div"></div>
  <div id="chart2_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.. But, i want the filter for both the charts. As in, when I select restaurants, I want aggregated restaurants- coverage data in 1st chart and aggregated restaurants - coverage change data in 2nd chart.

Comment: the agg chart is filtered by using the data table from the other chart...